# Write 'there exists' or 'for any' constraints for mip tool python

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization

How to write there exists or for any constraint for mip solver in python?

I want to write a constraint in which a binary variable's value is dependent on a list of binary variables. I just want to check if there exists a value with value 1 in the list and assign it to the binary variable.

Comment: Please make it clear what you're asking for. You need to include your input and expected output, including your attempt at a solution.

Comment: s1- binary variable
s- list of binary variables

s1=1     if for any i in s, s[i]==1
   =0      otherwise
  
How to write this constraint for the Python MIP solver?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following constraints (pseudo-code):

```
s1 <= sum(s)
M*s1 >= sum(s)
```

where M can be set to the size of s.